# Conectarse a un servidor dns

Tags: dns

Tengo un servidor con la ip 10.0.2.15 y quiero configurar la interfaz de red de un cliente Debian para que se conecte a este servidor.

Información de la interfaz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando comprubo si se me añadio como cliente visualizando el fichero resolv.conf no me detecta el nombre del dominio ni sus ip.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**--- MODIFICACION ---**
Configuración de la interfaz de red

```
# the loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interfaces
auto enp0s3
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
    address 10.0.2.18
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.2.2
    dns-nameservers 10.0.2.15 10.0.2.16 8.8.8.8
    dns-search 2daw.edu
```

Fichero resolv.conf

```
domain Home
search Home
nameserver 213.60.205.175
nameserver 213.60.205.173
```

Comment: me cuesta ver tus imágenes, podrías ponerlo como texto?

Comment: @Ruslan López acabo de hacer la modificación que me sugeriste